# UITableViewCell with accessory

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I got an app with UITableView. Every cell has accessory. But i cant set backgroundColor ti this cells.

[image]

I tried to set backgrounColors in this ways:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But only contentView work. How can i do it? Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second way `cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` is not that wrong. Unfortunately there is no backgroundView until you create one. You have to create an UIView and set it as background of the cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    background.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.backgroundView = background;
}
```